# What is this property on vertex contractions called?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given two quotient graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ of a simple graph $G$ such that the vertices of no edge in $G$ remain distinct in both $G_1$ and $G_2$, i.e. they have been contracted into one in $G_1$, $G_2$, or both. What is this relationship between $G$, $G_1$, and $G_2$ called? Has this relationship been researched before?

I am interested in this property because the distance between two vertices in $G$ is never greater than the sum of distances between the same vertices in $G_1$ and $G_2$, making such vertex contractions very valuable for use with the A* algorithm.

Comment: The question makes no sense. Give a better definition of $G_1$ and $G_2$ please. (an example might help)

Comment: @DanRust Someone “improved” my question by butchering its meaning. I just undid this improvement. “Remains distinct” is meant as in “the same edge still exists in the quotient graph, i.e. the vertices connected by the edge have not been contracted into one vertex.”